# Drop files from a form into a mail outlook 2016 do not work

Tags: c#, email, listview, outlook, drag-and-drop

My code was working with Outlook 2010. Now with Outlook 2016 it didn't work! I have seen other questions with the same problem, but they have no answer. i am new. Is my question stupid? Is there a solution? Do i have to search on Outlook side?
Thank you in advance.

```
private void item_Drag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lvdd = (ListView)sender;


    if (!lvdd.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        return;

    string[] fileName = new String[lvdd.SelectedItems.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvdd.SelectedItems)
    {
        fileName[i] = lvi.SubItems[1].Text;
        i++;
    }
    DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, fileName );
    data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, true, fileName[0]);


   lvdd.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

In fact i think that it dropped the name of the file, but not the file itself.
But why it was working before?